# VB.Net SQL Insert Statement seems to work but doesn't actually change Database

Tags: vb.net, oledb

This is the code:

```
    Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO StudentTable(BadgeNo,FirstName,LastName,SAPID,Email,Phone,College) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""C:\Users\larsennicholasg\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SSCLogin\SSCLogin\My Project\SSCStudent.mdb"""
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr), cmd As New OleDbCommand(insertSql, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(BadgeNoTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = FirstNameTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = LastNameTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(SAPSIDTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = EmailTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = PhoneTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = CollegeComboBox.Text

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        conn.Close()

    End Using
```

It passes through the program fine (finally), however doesn't actually seem to update the database at all.  Is there a save command, or a push command I'm missing?

What I'd like is it to take this information and insert it into the table, so if the program closes, it's still in the database.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is a function returning the number of rows affected, so that might be the first thing to check.  Otherwise, how are you determining it is not adding?  If the DB is part of the project, you may have it set to copy a fresh copy each time your run it in VS

Comment: Are you actually using 7 question marks for parameter names or are those placeholders?

Comment: I've learned this pretty much without a reference guide, as far as I know the ?'s are placeholders for Queries, which are then pushed by cmd.  I don't really know exactly what they do.  Bad, yes.  But I can't find a good guide on this particular subject

Comment: @pseudocoder OleDb doesnt use named parameters so MSDN suggests using `?`  changed the mySQL tag to OleDb because mySQL is a different database altogether

Comment: I know they prevent SQL Injection, or help at least.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm using the DB as part of the project, however I have the page after this command pull everything from the DB.  It shows the dummy row that I have but that's all.

Comment: In Solution Explorer, look at the properties for the DB - if `Copy To Output Directory` is "Copy Always" then it is providing you with a new empty DB each time so that you dont end up with lots of test data in yourDB when you are done.

Comment: It was set to Copy Always, and Build action is set to Content, I set it to Do not copy.  However still no updating, now my program doesn't end, I basically have to stop debugging to close the program.  Could that cause this?  Also could running it in Debug mode?

Comment: The program ending is a different problem.  Changing the DB build action wont change how it executes.  That DB access method is problematic - if this will be distributed, the hardcoded connection string will be wrong.  I'd place the DB in a Users folder; and use Access to look at the DB to see if rows are added, your "next page" code could be wrong (its possible for an app to have more than one problem at a time).

Comment: To prevent this from going on longer, what do you recommend me doing?